# Palindrome code not working well in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is a assignment I'm doing and it seems I can't get it to work properly.

The question is below.

> A palindrome is a word or phrase that reads the same forward and
>   backward, ignoring blanks and considering uppercase and lowercase
>   versions of the same letter to be equal.for example,the following are
>   palindromes:
>
> 1. warts n straw
> 2. radar
> 3. able was I ere I saw Elba
> 4. xyzczyx
>
> Write a program that will accept a sequence of characters terminated
>   by a period and will decide whether the string--without the
>   period---is a palindrome.You may assume that the input contains only
>   letters and blanks and is at most 80 characters long.Include a loop
>   that allows the user to check additional strings until she or he
>   requests that the program end.
>
> Hint:  Define a static method called `isPalindrome` that begins as
>   follows:
>
> Precondition:      The array a contains letters and blanks in
>   positions `a[0]` through `a[used - 1]`. Returns true if the string is a
>   palindrome and false otherwise.
>
> `public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] a, int used)`
>
> Your program should read the input characters into an array whose base
>   type is char and then call the preceding method. The int variable used
>   keeps track of how much of the array is used, as described in the
>   section entitled "Partially Filled Arrays."

This is my class code:

```
public class Palindrome_class 
{
// instance variable
char[] characterArray;

//constructor
//@param data is a string of characters
public Palindrome_class(String data)
{
    characterArray = data.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
}

//@return true if the word is a palindrome, otherwise returns false.
public boolean isPalindrome(char[] a, int used)
{
    int i = 0, j = used - 1;

    while (i < j)
    {
        if(characterArray[i] == characterArray[j])
        {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is my main code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class palindromeTest 
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int used = 0;
    char[] chars = new char[80];
    Scanner inputWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner reply = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string characters, terminated by a period.");

    String data;
    String cq;
    Palindrome_class word;

    do
    {
    //input word from user.
        data = inputWord.nextLine();
        word = new Palindrome_class(data);

    //check for palindrome.
        if(word.isPalindrome(chars, used))
        System.out.println(data + " is a palindrome.");

        else
        System.out.println(data + " is not a palindrome.");

    //request to continue or quit.
        System.out.println("Continue or Quit?");
        cq = reply.nextLine();
    }
    while (cq.equalsIgnoreCase("continue"));

    System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

This is the results:

Enter a string characters, terminated by a period.

radar.

radar. is a palindrome.

Continue or Quit?

continue

use

use is a palindrome.

Continue or Quit?

continue

use.

use. is a palindrome.

Continue or Quit?

continue

apple.

apple. is a palindrome.

Continue or Quit?

Quit

Please tell me where I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking whether a String is a palindrome with this call :

```
if(word.isPalindrome(chars, used))
```

However, `used` is 0, so your method always returns true.

You are also ignoring the instructions of your assignment. You are not doing anything with the `chars` array, you are not removing the period that's supposed to be at the end of the input String, your `isPalindrome` method is not static, etc...

Comment: `chars` is also never assigned and in fact `char[] a` is never used inside `isPalindrome()`.

Answer (score 0):

U did a very little mistake.. U are sending "used"  variable as 0 each time. ideally it should be length of a word.
please check it. use

```
used = data.length();
```

before sending it to the check method